# Hidden field equations - existence of zeroes

Tags: multivariate-cryptography, hidden-field-equation

Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be a finite field of size $q$ (prime), and $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$ be a degree-$n$ algebraic extension of $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Let $F$ be a polynomial function $\mathbb{F}_{q^n} \to \mathbb{F}_{q^n}$ of the form
$$
\sum_{i, j \in I_A} A_{i,j} X^{q^i + q^j} + \sum_{i\in I_B} B_i X^{q^i} + C
$$
where $A_{i,j}, B_i,$ and $C$ are some constants in $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$.

Given a random $D \in \mathbb{F}_{q^n}$, we need to find a solution $X$ for $F(X) = D$.

My question is: why does such a solution exist? Does the range of $F$ cover $\mathbb{F}_\mathbb{q^n}$? How do we check?

Answer (score 1):

Such a solution does not necessarily exist unless $F(X)$ is a [permutation polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_polynomial#Single_variable_permutation_polynomials_over_finite_fields) over $\mathbb F_{q^n}$.

Permutation polynomials are precisely those whose range covers the whole field.

The paper [Recognising permutation functions in polynomial time](https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2005/008/download/) (by Neeraj Kayal, one of the authors of the AKS polynomial time primality test) gives a polynomial time test.

Comment: Even, it is a permutation polynomial ( there is no simple kernel of $F$ that I can see) the question is not totally unanswered; how to find the solution.

Comment: The questioner did not ask how to find the unique solution, but as with all finite fields it can be found by taking a GCD with $X^{q^n}-X$.